# Why is DOM only being updated when debugging?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have built a wrapper around a function that display a loading progress bar and makes it disappear after the function executed. Now it does not display the progress bar, except when I set a breakpoint at the execution of the function foo.

I had a bit of success with running it on the progress onload event, but then it does not execute the `endLoading`:

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++)
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds) break;
}

var progress = document.createElement('progress');
var fillElement = document.body;

function foo() {
  console.log('foo start');
  sleep(2000);
  fillElement.innerHTML = 'Bar';
  console.log('foo end');
}

function startLoading() {
  console.log('start');
  fillElement.innerHTML = '';
  fillElement.appendChild(progress);
}

function endLoading() {
  console.log('end');
  fillElement.removeChild(progress);
}

startLoading();
foo(); // if the debug point is set here i can see the progress bar
endLoading();
```

Comment: use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) instead of busy looping.

Comment: Browsers are single threaded, and things will run to completion before anything else happens.  This means DOM repainting won't happen until your javascript has finished.  Having a breakpoint allows the script to pause, and the browser will use the time to do a repaint to reflect the current state of what the javascript is intended to have created in the DOM.

Comment: YOU CAN NOT DO SLEEP in JavaScript. BAD BAD idea... That for loop does not allow the DOM to update.

Comment: I changed and to it works, thx.

Comment: js is async scrypt language, so endLoading() function are executed almost simultaneously with startLoading(). Try to add endLoading() logic into some other place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function foo() { 
  console.log('foo start'); 
  setTimeout(function () {
    fillElement.innerHTML = 'Bar'; 
    console.log('foo end');
  }, 2000);
}
```

should do the equivalent of

```
function foo() { 
  console.log('foo start'); 
  sleep(2000);
  fillElement.innerHTML = 'Bar'; 
  console.log('foo end'); }
```

and you can chain together operations

```
startLoading(chain(foo, endLoading)); 

function chain(x, y) {
  return function () { x(y); }
}

function foo(afterwards) {
  console.log('foo start');
  setTimeout(
    function () {
      fillElement.innerHTML = 'Bar'; 
      console.log('foo end');
      afterwards();
    },
    2000);
}
```

and do a similar continuation-passing transform on `startLoading`.  You can also look into futures which can simplify some of this style of coding.